# Can I create a std::vector of a struct without defining the struct first?

Tags: c++, stl

Instead of:

```
struct MyStruct{
    ...
};

std::vector<MyStruct> myVec;
```

Can I do something like:

```
std::vector<struct MyStruct {...}> myVec;
```

or even, since I don't need a name for this struct as I'm only using it inside this vector:

```
std::vector<struct {...}> myVec?
```

I'm using C++ for many years and I don't think it's possible. I think it would be nice though...

Or is there a way?

Comment: You can't do that, unless you settle for a `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, any type stored in a standard container (dunno why you reference STL, which is similar but different and in any case ambiguous!) must be complete. A (forwand-)declared type is not complete. If you want to know, please check the standard of the version you are using or at least mention that here.

Concerning the inline declaration of a struct in a template parameter, e.g. `g++` says "types may not be defined in template arguments" when I try that. I can't give you a convincing reason why that shouldn't work. After all, all containers supply an `element_type` alias and with `auto` from C++ 11 that shouldn't be a problem in general.

Comment: You can't use them because they have no linkage (i.e., you can't find the ctor or dtor)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, @Artyer.

Comment: When the template is instantiated, it gets the type as a symbol. structs declared in template parameters are unnamed, so they don't have a symbol name, so can't be used to instantiate a template (because the classes name incorporates the symbols passed to it, and also it can't use any members of the struct since it can't find them by name). They have "no linkage".

Answer (score 0):

Both of the previous answers are correct - you cannot define a vector of something of incomplete type.

However, you can *declare* one - with the requirement that when you define it the type must be complete.

```
struct Foo; // forward declaration
using FooV = std::vector<Foo>; // declaration

struct Foo { int val; }; // definition
FooV v; // define a vector - all is well.
```

Answer (score -2):

**No**, you cannot do that when you declare an actual variable or type, as C++ is a staticly typed language. The C++ construct to allow for general types are templates, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
using myVec = std::vector<T>;
```

which you can use directly, e.g.

```
struct someStruct { /* ... */ };
myVec<someStruct> foo;
```

or in some template code

```
template<typename T>
T bar(myVec<T> const&vec)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I don't see how it's relevant that C++ is a statically typed language.